# Why jQuery Sortable returns double array brackets in serialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a simple html list:

```
<ol class="elements">
    <li class="">CONTAINER 1
        <ol>
            <li data-id="2" class="">CONTAINER 2
              <ol>
                  <li data-id="8" class="">First</li>
                  <li data-id="6" class="">Second</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
         </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

and serialize list in onDrop event:

```
var data = container.el.closest('.elements').sortable("serialize").get();
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data, null, '');
```

Then the plugin serializes this into the following string:

```
[[{"children":[[{"id":2,"children":[[{"id":8},{"id":6}]]}]]}]]
```

So for each container plugin creates **arrray of array** of child elements. 
What should i do to prevent that behavior?

Comment: I guess this happens cause u can do a .sortable() in an array of elements that your css query matches. Example: u can do $("div.sort").sortable("serialize") and have two (or more) div.sort in your html, so you will have one array per div.sort

Comment: But then, isn't this necessary only on the first level? When I serialize multiple list at a time, I have array of arrays (serialized lists) and on the higher level I should have been given one dimentional arrays of list elements... Meybe I should go deeper and ask Dicaprio... -_-